# JSON Binding @JsonbTypeDeserializer annotation ignored on enums?

Tags: java, resteasy, jsonb-api, yasson

I'm converting a JAXB application to [JSON-B](http://json-b.net/docs/user-guide.html) and I've run into an issue while trying to deserialize a Java enum using a custom `JsonbDeserializer` inside one of my tests.

The original JSON I need to deserialize contains `int`s referencing the enum's constants. Therefore my custom `JsonbDeserializer` needs to take the `int` and return the enum constant with the matching `ordinal`. It looks like this:

```
@JsonbTypeDeserializer(Region.RegionDeserializer.class)
public enum Region implements BaseEnum {

    REGION_A,
    REGION_B;

    static final class RegionDeserializer implements JsonbDeserializer<Region> {

        // deserialize() method returns REGION_A for 0 and REGION_B for 1.

    }
}
```

Then I run it like this:

```
try (var jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create()) {
    var result = jsonb.fromJson(text, Region.class);
} catch (final Exception ex) {
    fail(ex);
}
```

Unfortunately, here's what I get back:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant Region.1
    at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.EnumTypeDeserializer.deserialize(EnumTypeDeserializer.java:40)
```

As you can see, `RegionDeserializer` is not used. Instead, the default enum deserializer is used. Looking into the JSON-B docs, I see I should register the deserializer manually:

```
JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig()
    .withDeserializer(RegionDeserializer.class);
Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create(config);
...
```

And when I do that, the code in fact works. But here's my question - what can I do to have the `JsonbTypeDeserializer` annotation registered automatically? Considering I have a lot of enums I need custom deserializers for, registering them manually really doesn't scale.

**EDIT 1:** I have tried to use `@JsonbCreator`-annotated static method instead, and the result was the same. The default enum deserializer was still used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON-B specification mentions both ways of registering the custom deserializer:

> There are two ways how to register JsonbSerializer/JsonbDeserializer:
>
> - Using `JsonbConfig::withSerializers`/`JsonbConfig::withDeserializers` method;
> - Annotating a type with `JsonbSerializer`/`JsonbDeserializer` annotation.

The fact that the annotation does not work is a bug. I could reproduce this on Yasson 1.0.6, but not on Yasson 2.0.0-M1. Perhaps updating to the latest version solves your problem?

Comment: I agree that it does appear to be a bug. I will file it with the project.

Comment: Do you know if this bug has been resolved? Because I think I'm facing with the same problem.

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue on Yasson 2.0.0-M1. What version are you using, @freedev?

Comment: @Martijn thanks for coming back, not sure what version I'm using because it's a dependence not defined by me. But I found a **working** solution here https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/post/jsonb-enum-serialization. Hope this helps