# Annotations from javax.xml.bind.annotation not working on payara 5 jdk 11

Tags: java, docker, jakarta-ee, java-11, payara

I'm using `docker payara/server-full:5.2020.5-jdk11 image`. I deployed the java ee app built with `JDK 11`. I have some DTOs, in which I have annotations like:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateTimeAdapter.class)
private Date creationDate;

private SomeEnum enumm;

@XmlEnum
public enum SomeEnum {
@XmlEnumValue("U")
USER;
}
```

and these annotations are not working (while making rest requests). There is no error in runtime. Annotations are just ignored. I tested adding ie throw exception in adapter and nothing happened.

I read about that in JDK 11 this package is excluded, and I also added the recommended dependencies to the `pom`, but still no difference. And, as I said, I have no error.

Comment: Did you deploy the dependencies?

Comment: Inside .ear i have .war, and inside it in web-inf\lib i can find these dependencies

Comment: Have you added the `jaxb-impl` into your application as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48204154/784594? is the `jaxb-impl` JAR in your web-inf/lib folder in the WAR?

Answer (score -1):

I need to mention, that i'm making the migration from payara 4.

I think that my problem is related to those topics: 
[JSON Binding @JsonbTypeDeserializer annotation ignored on enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60572894/json-binding-jsonbtypedeserializer-annotation-ignored-on-enums) 
[Glassfish 5 ignores JAXB @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47825336/glassfish-5-ignores-jaxb-xmljavatypeadapter-annotation) 
[How do I configure Glassfish 5 to use Moxy as the default Provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58083386/how-do-i-configure-glassfish-5-to-use-moxy-as-the-default-provider)

For now I decided to use:

```
@JsonbDateFormat
// and
@JsonbTypeAdapter
```

as a replacement.